# Ошибка Е2285 в С++

Tags: c++builder, borland

При компиляции программы выдает ошибку в строке `Prac_Batko object2(15, "Mark", 2, "Julia");`.

> E2285 Could not find a match for 'Prac_Batko::Prac_Batko(int,char*,int,char*)'

Программка учебная, мой уровень - начальный в ООП, глаза уже просто не видят, где ошибка. Буду очень благодарна за подсказку.

```
class Pracivnyk{

    int id;
    char name[20];
    public:
    Pracivnyk(void){
        cout<<"Constructor Pracivnyk"; id=0; strcpy(name,"void");
    }

    Pracivnyk(int a_id, char *nm){
        cout<<"Constructor Pracivnyk"; id=a_id; strcpy(name, nm);
    }


    void assignid(int a_id){
        id=a_id;
    }

    int accessid(void){
        return id;
    }

    void assignName(char *nm){
        strcpy(name, nm);
    }

    char *accessName(void){
        return name;
    }
};

class Batko_simeystva{

    int kol_det;
    public:
    Batko_simeystva(void){
        cout<<"Constructor Batko"; kol_det=0;
    }

    Batko_simeystva(int i_kol_det){
        cout<<"Constructor Batko"; kol_det=i_kol_det;
    }

    void assignkol_det(int i_kol_det){
        kol_det=i_kol_det;
    }

    int accesskol_det(void){
        return kol_det;
    }   
};

class Prac_Batko: public Pracivnyk,public Batko_simeystva
{

    char szena;
    public:
    Prac_Batko(void){
        cout<<"Constructor Prac_Batko"; szena = 'Anna';
    }

    Prac_Batko(int a_id, char *nm, int i_kol_det, char sz): Pracivnyk(a_id, nm),Batko_simeystva(i_kol_det) {

        cout<<"Constructor Prac_Batko"; szena = sz;
    }

    void assign(char sz){
        szena=sz;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Prac_Batko& Pd);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Prac_Batko& Pd)
{
    char sz;
    os<<"id"<<Pd.accessid()<<"name"<<Pd.accessName()<<"Kol_det"<<Pd.accesskol_det()<<"Szena"<< sz;
    return os;
}


main()
{
    Prac_Batko object1; cout<<object1;
    Prac_Batko object2(15, "Mark", 2, "Julia");
    cout<<object2;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Я ни разу не сишник, просто мимо проходил, но может быть ты * в четвертом аргументе второго конструктора Prac_Batko забыл?

Comment: Приведя оформление вашего вопроса в порядок, вероятность получения ответа сильно возрастет.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не используйте транслитерацию с вашего родного языка для названий переменных, классов, полей, объектов или чего-либо ещё в вашем коде. Если вы когда-нибудь станете профессиональным программистом, велика вероятность, что работать вам придётся в мультинациональной команде, а посему для именований следует использовать принятый для этого международным сообществом язык - английский. Лучше начинать привыкать к этому прямо сейчас, потому что потом будет гораздо сложнее переучиваться.

Comment: Замечания принимаются, учту на будущее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, у вас в конструкторе `Prac_Batko(int a_id, char *nm, int i_kol_det, char sz)` четвёртый аргумент `sz` — один символ.

А вы туда передаёте строку `"Julia"`. Вот и ошибка.

---

И ради бога, никогда не пользуйтесь транслитом для идентификаторов! Английский и только английский.

Answer (score 0):

Это один символ, а не строка:

```
char szena;
```

Поэтому вот этот код не имеет особого смысла:

```
szena = 'Anna';
```

Поменяйте тип у `szena`. Перепишите код, упоминающий `szena`, по аналогии с кодом, который работает с `name`.

Comment: Благодарю за ответы, и правда глупая ошибка.